# Php sitemap - listing only 11 pages while site has 3000 plus pages

Tags: php, mysql, sitemap

I am trying to generate a sitemap for my website, but whenever I try to generate the sitemap it shows only 11 pages, but there are multiple dynamically generated pages from the database.

I use [this](https://www.xml-sitemaps.com/). Before updating my site with a lot of changes, there were 3100 plus pages on the sitemap, now after adding more entries to the database, the sitemap seems to only pick up 11 pages.

Has anyone else encountered such an error and able to fix it? The site to which this happens - [This is the site](https://www.firstcrayon.com).

Comment: Well, such an external service can only reach and detect those contents that are referenced in some way. Most likely that is not the case here.

Comment: What does that mean? I am not using this site, I am using their standalone generator on my site. But the same issue even then.

Comment: what is your site? give samples of your page links..

Comment: Does not matter whether standalone or online service. Sites not referenced cannot be found.

Comment: @arkascha true, the service is finding pages to which links are given in some or other ways.. it does not take into consideration dynamic pages.

Comment: @Gunnrryy the site is given at the end of my question with a hyperlink. Someone edited it to be that way, not sure why.

Comment: @Hdman your issue is the dynamic pages
searchpreschools.php?city=Mumbai&location=&typeahead=&category=3,  the pages depend upon filters like city, location, category etc. which are not actually mentioned anywhere in your web pages. the service scans your pages and fetches the page links that it can find and gives you.. not the dynamic pages. pls try to understand that

Comment: @Gunnrryy thanks. yes I realized that, what would be a solution to make sure I get those pages indexed?

Comment: You can easily implement a short script iterating over all combination of dynamic arguments, thus creating a list of all such pages. If you include such a list as page references somewhere in your site, for example as html sitemap, then all sitemap generators and robots will be able to find those pages. Take care to keep such list dynamically created itself, so that it updates itself without you having to invest time into maintaining it.

Comment: create a script and iterate of all possible permutation & combination of links.
put your logic in making the available links and push them in an array.

Comment: create a script that would generate all links that you can possibly have in your website, like `domain.com/?city=5&type=p` assume your link is like that and the parameters passed are present in database. either save the results in an array or directly map them to your sitemap.xml

Comment: I really would only like the school profile pages to appear. For example the school profiles are at https://www.sitename.com/preschool/school-name how will I be able to get a list of all the pages associated with the url /preschool?

Comment: @Gunnrryy, so I just create a html file that gets all links from the site, and then connect it to the sitemap.xml? How do I connect it?

Comment: @mrahmat thanks for your suggestion, I would generate all links into a .txt or .php file? I am confused as to how I will connect it to sitemap.

Comment: could you please specify what exactly you want to do with the sitemap? as of now generating sitemap was concern. plesase explain your purpose, issue in a way it is understandable for quicker solution to problem

Comment: @Hdman just directly create the sitemap without saving the links, directly export them to a .xml file as a sitemap